# Tcp application throughput

Tags: sockets, tcp, throughput

I have two machines: A server and a client, connected through TCPsockets. The server is a sensor, that sends data to the client, and the client does some processing with the data. I want to know if my client is losing packet from the server in the data processing. I mean, if there is packet loss while the client application reads a package and processes it. At least the network is fine, because the machines are connected directly through Ethernet. Doing some research, I read about the /proc/net/tcp (in the client) and checked if the ports of the system have packets in the input queue, and fortunately there is no package in the input queue. But, is that enough to know if the server-client system does have package loss?

Thanks

Comment: What is your outer problem? Why do you want this information and what do you plan to do with it? (It makes a difference.)

Comment: I want to know if my client application is losing data from the server (the sensor). This information is useful for me for 1) If I can prove my client has enough throughput, I can stop worrying about that and move on another topic, and 2) If my client has not enough throughput, improve the data processing in the client.

Comment: TCP packet loss has nothing to do with application throughput.